# xpages and dojo.query and get parent in view panel

Tags: view, dojo, xpages, panel

I am building an application on xpages and I am using the code [Code](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=viewpanelhelper-to-keep-selection-of-documents-in-a-view) published in Open NTF XSnippets.

The code works when I have only one view panel, however when I have more than one, it shares the function variables. I thought about getting the id of the view panel in the code snippet below, to be able to conditionally treat the view panel. But I have not seen a function for the element xspCheckBoxViewColumn takes the id of the view panel.

```
 dojo.query(".xspCheckBoxViewColumn").connect('onclick', function() {

if (id== id current view panel)
```

I accept other suggestions to address the problem.

Comment: Did you try: "if(id == this.id)" ?

Comment: Actually, it does not give the id of the column checkbox, and I want to compare the id of the view panel with the parameter I will pass, as the name of the view panel being manipulated. What I want is from the child that is the checkbox of the column of the view panel, reach the ID of the view panel.